# C FOR Condition

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I need to create a simple program which asks for 10 numbers from user and then shows the sum of those numbers or, if the user gives 0 as input, stops and immediately displays the sum of those numbers, and I need to create it only by using a "for" condition. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int num = 0;
for(num = 0; num < 10; num++){
    printf("Input a number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if(num == 0){
        printf("Sum: %d\n", num);
    }
}
printf("Sum: %d\n", num);
getchar();
getchar();
}
```

It stops only when the number is greater than "10".Whats wrong?

Comment: FYI, there is no logic in your code to perform `Sum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do this kind of work with your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int num = 0;
int sum=0;
for(num = 0; num < 10; num++){
   int i;
   printf("Input a number: \n");
   scanf("%d", &i);
   sum = sum+i;
   if(i == 0){
      printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
      getchar();
      return 0;
   }
}
printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although correct, isn't it a bit weird to have the same piece of code twice in the program, while the if body could be reduced to a simple break statement?

Comment: Well if we use break statement the code will then perform 2 extra task namely "printf() and getchar()", But if we use return 0 it will terminate immediately.

Comment: The getchar() statement is placed there because, otherwise, the program would terminate and probably the window hosting the program would close. That way, the user would have no way of reading the sum, as the windows would disappear nearly-instantly after the sum would be displayed. Also, I'm suggesting you remove both the printf and the return statements from the if body and only keep a break statement.

Comment: Thats correct. I should use one getchar() before return 0; thanks @naltipar

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is, you're using the same variable `num` both as counter and for taking user input which is breaking the logic in `for` loop.

Use another variable for taking user input.

Also, you've to have a `break` statement to discontinue the `for` loop once you've got the breaking criteria.

Note: as I mentioned in my comments, there is no logic for `Sum`.

---

Check the below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
        int num = 0;
        int sum = 0;    //to hold the sum
        int input = 0;
        for(num = 0; num < 10; num++){
                printf("Input a number: \n");
                scanf("%d", &input);
                sum += input;                  // yoo-hoo, time to add-up
                if(input == 0){
                        printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
                        break;               // time to say bye-bye to for loop
                }
        }
        if (num == 10)              //only print if not printed previously
        printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes you are write i add another variable and it stops only after 10 inputed numbers but doesnt show the write sum

Comment: i change only this:  int sum;
 for(sum = 0; sum < 10; sum++){

Comment: @Dimitri you've to add a `break` statement , too. hang on, a solution is on the way. :-)

Comment: @Dimitri with all due respect, which part of `hang on, a solution is on the way` was not understood ?

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
 int num = 0;
 int sum;
 for(sum = 0; sum < 10; sum++){
  printf("Introduza um numero: \n");
  scanf("%d", &num);
  if(num == 0){
   printf("Soma: %d\n", num);
   break;
  }
 }
 printf("Soma: %d\n", num);
 getchar();
 getchar();
}`

Comment: @Dimitri I'm extremely sorry, but a code in a _comment_ is not so good to be read by humans. Why don't you try out the code given in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the value of the counter inside the for loop. That's why, when you read a value greater than or equal to 10, it will abandon the for loop, since you have the condition `num < 10`.

Let me tweak the code for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int sum = 0;
    int i;
    int num;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("Input a number: \n");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        sum += num;
        if(num == 0){
            break; //means leave the loop
        }
    }
    printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using 3 variables:

1. `sum`, which is used to store the overall sum.
2. `i`, which is used as the `for loop` counter.
3. `num`, which is used to store the current number given by the user.

First of all, I'm waiting for an input:

```
printf("Input a number: \n");
scanf("%d", &num);
```

Now, the input is stored in num, so I'm upgrading the sum, to add the new value:

```
sum += num;
```

The I check if the current number is zero; in that case I'll just leave the loop:

```
if(num == 0){
   break;
}
```